# How to setup a webserver to run inline ruby?

Tags: php, web-server, ruby

I would like to run inline ruby code embedded in some kind of html webpage. There are ruby servers around like mongrel, thin, but I just wanted to run inline ruby in html without making a so called ruby app conforming to some framework I don't want to learn. I want the ruby code to act like PHP, so that I can access the Database, print out forms and so on.

What setup should I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly, I have never done this, but [mod_ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_ruby) should be able to do this. If you are able to install mod_php, you are able to use mod_ruby.

Where embedded PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
    print("Hello world");
?>
```

embedded Ruby would look like this:

```
<% var="Hello world %>
<%= var %>
```

Or something similar; haven't done this for some time ;-) More syntax stuff to be found [here](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/web.html). To make a long story short: install mod_ruby and you should be good to go.

Comment: For people who want to install Mod_ruby, eruby onto apache under Ubuntu, visit this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-356350.html. The info is a bit dated, but it still works! Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895683/is-there-a-phpish-way-of-doing-webpages-with-ruby/1901772#1901772) to a similar question on SO. It's a bit similar to Daniel's answer, but I've created a ruby-cgi script that does some "magic" for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) is minimal enough to stay out of your way (and not tell you what to do), but fully featured enough that you can get going quickly and without much effort.

You get routes, views (Erb or HAML/SaSS), helpers, filters and support for various database adapters for free. Sinatra doesn't make any assumptions about what you'll be doing. Your project can be as simple or as complex as necessary. More importantly, the documentation is *excellent* and there are *good examples* (of real projects!).

Sinatra applications are easy to deploy using any rack compliant HTTP server such as Mongrel or Thin.

Comment: Not too sure I can embed code within html with sinatra

Comment: You certainly can

Answer (score 0):

Two other options is using either [erb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/) and cgi(2) or eruby(3) (if you're having trouble installing mod_ruby):

1. `erb` with a `*.rb`-controller-sort-of.
   This requires two files for a page, but makes for some simple separation of logic
   and view (without a "framework").

   It's really easy to setup, just one line in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` (given executable permissions):

   ```
   AddHandler cgi-script .rb
   ```

   Your `mypage.eruby` is a php-like ERB-template:

   ```
   <p>Hello <%= foo %>!</p>
   ```

   But it involves some coding to use. In your `mypage.rb` file:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby
   require 'cgi'
   require 'erb'

   # Use cgi for handling params and sending headers etc.
   cgi = CGI.new

   # connect to db etc.

   # prepare variables (Or rather some object to bind to - read docs for that ...)
   foo = "World"

   # read in your template
   template = ERB.new(File.read('mypage.eruby'))
   content = template.result

   # Print stuff
   print cgi.header
   print content
   ```

   Now request `mypage.rb`
2. Use the `eruby` executable (more like classic php-style).
   Maybe easier for simple scripts.

   Download the eruby executable (there is probably a binary for your platform) and
   copy it to `/cgi-bin/eruby`

   In `httpd.conf`:

   ```
   AddType application/x-httpd-eruby .rhtml
   Action application/x-httpd-eruby /cgi-bin/eruby
   ```

   Then create your `mypage.rhtml`:

   ```
   <% 
       # Do ruby stuff here, connect to DB etc.
       foo = "World"
   %>
   <p>Hello <%= foo %>!</p>
   ```

   Now request `mypage.rhtml`

I prefer 1, but 2 might feel easier to begin with once eruby is installed. Please excuse me for any errors - I haven't tested my suggested config and code.

(I'm to new to post working links. I'll appreciate if someone with permissions like to fix them.)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple setup is to use [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) (a web application server capable of running **any Ruby rack application**, which works both standalone or as an apache/ngix module) + [rack server pages](https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages) gem (which is a small rack application allowing you to serve simple HTML pages with embedded Ruby code).

Using Passenger in the standalone mode, you only need to run "passenger start" in the root directory of the files you want to serve, and have in that folder, a config.ru file with just 2 lines:

```
require 'rack-server-pages'
run Rack::ServerPages
```

You can now serve any .erb files by putting them in the `public` subfolder.

You could also just run "rackup" and let the pages be served by a ruby server of your choice.